# Deploy contract that requires an ERC20 object in constructor

Tags: solidity, web3js, ico, openzeppelin

I am starting an ICO and basing my contract on OpenZeppelin. I am trying to deploy the contract using web3.js and my problem is that in the constructor I need to pass the ERC20 object of my token. I am not sure how to do that. Do I need to pass the address of the token or the ABI or what exactly? I do not find any information on this anywhere.

This is my contract constructor:

```
function CrowdSale(uint256 _hivePerEther, address _wallet, ERC20 _token, uint256 _openingTime, uint256 _closingTime) public {

}
```

My question is how to load and pass my token to the constructor when deploying using web3.js

Answer (score 1):

yep, use the address. Your CrowdSale contract will also need to know what ERC20 tokens look like. So either paste the contract into the same CrowdSale.sol file or add `import '/path/to/ERC20.sol` into the same file

Answer (score 0):

declare an ERC20 interface, pass in an address, and then you can use the interface to declare an ERC20 token from the address. Something like this:

```
// Standard ERC20 Token Interface
interface ERC20Token {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256 _totalSupply);
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256 _balance);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool _success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool _success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) external returns (bool _success);
    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) external view returns (uint256 _remaining);

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
}

contract CrowdSale {

    ERC20Token token;

    constructor (uint256 _hivePerEther, address _wallet, address _token, uint256 _openingTime, uint256 _closingTime) public {
        token = ERC20Token(_token);
        ...
    }

    function getTokenBalance(address _addr) external view returns (uint256 _balance) {
         _balance = token.balanceOf(_addr);
    }
}
```