# Can i call transfer function in other contract?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

can i call ERC20 token's transfer function in other contract?
like transfer AToken from using BContract's function can I?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. You only need to import the ERC20 contract into your main contract, then you only need to pass the address of the token contract that you want to call its APIs. Like the following:

```
ERC20(TOKEN_ADDRESS).transfer(...)
```

Comment: is it possible to call transfer without import? ex) send Omisego via my contract function @abed

Comment: You only need to soecify the base ERC20 contract

Comment: you don't need to import anything, just declare the ERC20 interface, and wrap an address as an instance of the interface, and you can call all the ERC20 interface functions from your contract, including the transfer function. an example here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41760/deploy-contract-that-requires-an-erc20-object-in-constructor/73877#73877

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the transfer function of contract **A** by contract **B**. You just have to let contract **B** know how to communicate with contract **A**. To do this, you first create an interface in contract **B** that tells it which functions contract **A** has that you want to use. Then you create an instance of contract **A** in contract **B**. Here's a simple code snippet of how it works:

```
interface ERC20TokenInterface {
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool _success);
    // ... include other functions you also want to use here 
}

contract YourContract {
    ERC20TokenInterface otherContract = ERC20TokenInterface("0xf5b0a3efb8e8e4c201e2a935f110eaaf3ffecb8d");
    //replace the contract address above with the contract you want to communicate with

    function useTransfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        otherContract.transfer(_to, _value); // this code shows how you use the instance of contract A in contract B to do a transfer
    }
}
```